# Smarter compile in emacs

Tags: compilation, c, compilation-mode, ide, makefile-mode

I often got to work with projects organized as follows:

src/

include/

...

Makefile

Is there a way to teach emacs' "compile" function to always use that top-level Makefile regardless which file I'm editing in the current buffer? For example it can be any of

src/sub1/s1.c

include/protocol/p.h

src/x.c

tests/test1/test_x.c

In all those cases I want "compile" command to go as many times "up" in hierarchy as necessary to get into top-level directory (the one in the directory with 'src', 'include' and 'tests' entries) and run Makefile in there. Additional problem is that any of sub directories can have Makefiles of its own.

Comment: You should check out projectile. It has a handy function for this

Comment: You could write a function that uses `locate-dominating-file` on `default-directory` to find the top-level dir, then sets `default-directory` to that dir path and runs `compile`

Comment: Thanks for hint on projectile - will look into it. As for writing function - I'll leave it as a last resort - the task seems to be way to common so I'd rather not reinvent a wheel.